# How to generate website with menu from an ASCII-Doc file?

Tags: compilation, asciidoc, asciidoctor

I installed AsciiDoctor to generate html5-Websites from my ASCII-Doc files.

So far I did not find an option that generates a file like the one on e.g. http://www.asciidocfx.com/ or http://asciidoctor.org/docs/user-manual/ (i.e. (1) no footer with the date, (2) a menu on the left side and (3) linked headings.)

(How) Do I have to use templates for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what you mean by "I have installed AsciiDoctor" are you using the Ruby version, the JavaScript version or the JVM Version (Ruby + JRuby)? How are you using Asciidoctor, directly from the command line or integrated in an other build system?

(1) I think (I am not sure about this one) that the footer is created if you have set the parameter `docinfo1` to `true`. See [Footer docinfo files](http://asciidoctor.org/docs/user-manual/#footer-docinfo-files).

(2) The menu on the left is called [TOC (table of content)](http://asciidoctor.org/docs/user-manual/#user-toc), you might need add the parameter `toc` with the value `left`.

(3) The link on the headers are created when the parameter `sectanchors` has the value `true`. See the [Anchors](http://asciidoctor.org/docs/user-manual/#anchors) section.